# How can I extend UIViewController which is created by XIB?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, inheritance

I have a general view controller (created by XIB) with some common controls. I want to create child view controller which inherits that general view controller. I want use XIB at both parent view and child views. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

[See this tutorial that may help you](http://aseriesoftubes.com/articles/ipad-development-101-orientation/)

I think, this is same as you said you want to use same xib for both view controllers. You need to do some work around but don't work this tutorial will show you how do it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of your question, although it seems quite vague question -

1. I want to create child view controller which inherits that general view controller.
   you can simply use like - `ChildViewController : ParentViewController`
2. I want use XIB at both parent view and child views. 
   While loading these view controller you can use `initWithNibName: bundle:` and pass xib here.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. What I mean is: I have a parent view controller XIB called: ParentViewController.xib and 1 child view controller XIB called: ChildViewController.xib. I just want to create ChildViewController which inherit controls from ParentViewController  plus its own controls. How can I do this?

Comment: @pipu - the way in which i had suggested above.